# Default width and height of a View with wrap_content

Tags: android-view, android

When I create a custom `View`, and I draw it by adapting sizes in `View.onSizeChanged()`, what is the default size of the `View`? I my layout I have set the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 2):

The default size is 0.  Unless it has subviews (and is derived from a layout class which defines onLayout), in which case the default size is the sum of its children.  If you want to use wrap_content on a custom view that isn't just a collection of child views, you need to override on onLayout and/or onMeasure.

Comment: I have a subclass of `View` which doesn't contain any other `View`. I fill this class with some geometric figures that I draw on the `canvas`, so the default size should be 0. But with `wrap_content` to both `layout_height` and `layout_width` my view occupies the entire screen. All the sizes in my view are set in `onSizeChanged()` based on the arguments of that function. PS: I didn't override `onLayout` nor `onMeasure`.